# What is $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin(x-y)}{x^3-y^3}$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I've tried to prove it doesn't exist then I tried to find some sort of limited function inside of it that would help me out, nothing worked, I ran out of ideas for now.

Comment: I know that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}(x^3-y^3)=0$, so $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(x-y)}{x^3-y^3}$$ approaches $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\frac{\sin(x-y)}{x^3-y^3} = 
\frac{\sin(x-y)}{x-y} \cdot \frac{x-y}{x^3-y^3} = 
\frac{\sin(x-y)}{x-y} \cdot \frac{1}{x^2 + xy + y^2}
$$
Use also the fact that $\frac{\sin(z)}{z} \to 1$ when $z \to 0$.

Comment: So... if (x,y) tends to (0,0), the limit tends to infinity and because infinity is not real number, the limit actually doesn't exist, is this right?

Comment: A limit does not have to be a real number, it can be $\pm\infty$ as well. Thus, in your case the limit exists.

Comment: I think this is the thing that's confusing me because my professor said that when the limit tends to infinity, the limit doesn't exist, I guess it may be a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be the limit in question, we have: $x^2+xy+y^2 \ge 0, \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}\implies L = +\infty$ because the factor $\dfrac{\sin(x-y)}{x-y}$ tends to $1$ when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ .

Answer (score 1):

Look at a sequence:

$$x_{n}=\frac{2}{n},\quad y_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$$,

Then $(x_{n},y_{n})\rightarrow (0,0)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

Shove this is to your limit and see what happens.